# The effect of using DOM method normalize()

Tags: javascript, dom, normalize

It seems that I do not understand the exact action of the DOM method `normalize()`.

I thought that it removes entirely empty Text nodes. However I do not observe this effect.

Here is a sample document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html />

<html lang = "en">

<head>
    <meta charset = "Utf-8" />
    <title>Normalize</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form accept = "#" method = "post">
        <fieldset><legend>Using normalize()</legend>
        <p>The form is used only to test the method normalize().</p>
        <div>
            <label for = "text">Label</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "text" id = "text"/>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var element = document.getElementById("text");

            do {
                alert(element);
                element = element.previousSibling;
            } while (element.nodeType != Node.ELEMENT_NODE);

            alert(element);

            var element = document.getElementById("text");

            element.parentNode.normalize();

            do {
                alert(element);
                element = element.previousSibling;
            } while (element.nodeType != Node.ELEMENT_NODE);

            alert(element);
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The first `do-while` outputs nodes when method `normalize()` was not yet called.
Its output in `IE-11` is the following

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
[object Text]
[object HTMLLabelElement]
```

However after calling method `normalize()` the next `do-while` loop produces the same sequence of outputs:

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
[object Text]
[object HTMLLabelElement]
```

I thought that the output

```
[object Text]
```

should be absent in the second loop.

What is wrong in my understanding of the method `normalize()`?
Or what is the exact definition of the empty Text node in the DOM specification?

Comment: That is because the textnode between the element nodes is not actually empty but contains a newline as well as some space. Precisely the text node's value is `"↵      "` - Instead of alerting, if you log the nodes into the console, you can expand them and see the above. Like it is here: https://jsfiddle.net/m1pmL0at/

Comment: Also, if you force-empty textnodes (with just spaces and/or newlines in it) before normalizing, it works as expected. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/m1pmL0at/1/

Comment: @techfoobar Can you provide a reference to the exact definition of the empty Text node in the DOM specification? I can not find it myself.

Comment: Let me dig a little. From practical experience, I know it is one whose `nodeValue === ""`, but let me see if I can get you a formal reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'normalize' method definition says '*no text nodes in the sub-tree are empty and there are no adjacent text nodes*' In your case there is no text node which is empty, there is on text node which has "↵ " and some spaces. If you change your html to:

```
<label for = "text">Label</label><input type = "text" name = "text" id = "text"/>
```

'label' and 'input' element together without spaces, you will not get any alert for '#text' node. Now, if you really wanna see how normalize works, you should create two text nodes with empty values:

```
document.createTextNode('');
```

put them in between your 'label' and 'input' element. Then run your code. You will get two alerts for #text node. And after normalization you should not get any alert for #text node.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [normalize-page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize) it will remove empty text nodes and merge adjacent ones. In your case you have two html elements surrounding your textnode which will contain some whitespace so it won't be touched.

Comment: Bit isn't there an empty text node still in there? Interesting that the link you posted did not have empty text nodes

Comment: @Karl-Johan Sjögren  I though that an empty Text node is a text node that contains only white spaces. What is the exact definition of the term "empty tText node"?

Comment: The specification says empty and whitespace doesn't count as empty. See this jsbin for a sample: http://jsbin.com/digujopuro/edit?js,output
The first text node which is an empty string is completely removed while the last one is kept.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren It would be good if I get an exact reference to the DOM specification where the notion of empty Text node is defined.

Comment: The spec merely says "empty", but that seems clear enough to me.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I haven't found a reference in the DOM specification of it so I go by the literal meaning which wouldn't allow any chars in the string. My jsbin supports that also (by removing the empty string and keeping the one with a space in it).